# Query entity select, inner join and count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

i want to translate this SQL query :

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName, WaiterId, Count(*) AS compte 
FROM Waiter
INNER JOIN Client on Waiter.Id = Client.WaiterId
GROUP BY WaiterId,lastname, firstname 
ORDER BY compte DESC;
```

in entity framework.

I tried something like this :

```
           var query = (from w in db.Waiter
                     join c in db.Client on w.Id equals c.WaiterId
                     group c by c.WaiterId into g
                     //orderby 
                     select new
                     {
                         WaiterId = g.Key,
                         count = g.Count()
                     });
```

but my select don't work. I can't select FirstName and LastName and i don't even know if my count is good.

Comment: In you LINQ query, you are grouping by only WaiterId where as in your SQL query, you are grouping by WaiterID, LastName and FirstName. Adding those columns in your group by, should let you select them as well.

Comment: Oh yes ! I didn't see it before. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include all the properties in the group by.

```
var query = (from w in db.Waiter
             join c in db.Client on w.Id equals c.WaiterId
             group c by new { c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.WaiterId} into g
             orderby g.Count() descending
             select new
             {
                  FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
                  LastName  = g.Key.LastName,
                  WaiterId  = g.Key.WaiterId,
                  count     = g.Count()
              });
```

Comment: Well, i think that work. I can't try it now, but I c/c your code in my program and it return me 0 error. (it's w.Firstname, w.LastName btw :P). Thank you again !